# Creating a booking system, but I struggle with inserting the input date to MySQL table

Tags: mysql, reactjs, function, date, datetime

I am new to programming trying to create a rental system for cars with reactjs, node and mysql, but I struggle with inserting date to the database. I know I have to make it a string somehow and also make it local timezone, but can't figure it out.

date.js:

````
dateOut = "";
dateIn = "";
location = "";
render()
  return(
}
<input type="date" value={this.dateOut} onChange={e => (this.dateOut = e.target.value)} />
<input type="date" value={this.dateIn} onChange={e => (this.dateIn = e.target.value)} />
<input type="text" value={this.location} onChange={e => (this.location = e.target.value)}>
);

add() {
    orderService.addOrder(
      this.dateOut,
      this.dateIn,
      this.location
      id => {
        history.push('/cars/' + id);
      }
    );
  }
} ```

services.js:

  ```addOrder(dateOut, dateIn, location, success) {
    connection.query(
      'insert into Orders (dateOut, dateIn, location, success) values (?, ?, ?)',
      [dateOut, dateIn, location],
      (error, results) => {
        if (error) return console.error(error);

        success(results.insertId);
      }
    );
  } ```
````

Comment: you have not posted the error message you are getting, further it is difficult to find a problem when you show snippets of functions without the values. Some logging might help. furthermore you are mentioning your `success` variable in the SQL-statement which is definitely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to handle this.

1. Declare your `dateOut` and `dateIn` columns as `TIMESTAMP` data types in your table.
2. When you provide date/time values to your `insert` queries, use text strings with formats like `2019-04-08 16:52`. Or use Javascript Date objects.
3. When registering your users, ask for their timezone preference, specifically asking them to choose from one of the values in `mysql.time_zone_name.name`.
4. Store that preference, as a string (like `Asia/Kolkata` or `America/Halifax`) in your user preference table. `VARCHAR(63)` is a good choice of data type for that column.
5. Each time you use a MySQL connection in your app on behalf of a user, first issue the command `SET time_zone = whateverTheyChose` to set the user's time zone preference.

Why is this good?   `TIMESTAMP` data type values are always stored in UTC, and always translated to/from the currently set time zone when retrieving or storing them.

If you want to insert the present date/time value into a column, you can do something like this:

```
insert into Orders 
       (dateOut, dateIn, location, success) 
values (NOW(),    NOW(),        ?,       ?)
```

Notice how the values and placeholders in the `values()` clause correspond one-to-one with the items in the list of columns.

You can read about [MySQL's time zone handling system on the 'toobz](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html). It's based on [IANA's zoneinfo database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones). The maintainers of that database take care of all the strange temporopolitical considerations like when daylight time begins and ends in Turkmenistan or Indiana USA, so the rest of us don't have to.

If you use `DATE` or `DATETIME` data types rather than `TIMESTAMP`, you don't get that automatic time zone stuff. Those data types are, more or less, like photographs of clocks.

No matter which datatype you use, you can use the MySQL function called [TIMESTAMPDIFF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) to compute durations.  For example,

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, dateOut, dateIn)
```

tells you the number of hours between your two date/time values.  It will work correctly even if your two values span the daylight time switchover days.

It's worth a lot of your time to learn about how your dbms handles dates and times. They do it very well so you don't have to reinvent the flat tire.

And, it's worth your trouble to set up all this correctly very early in the life of your application.  It's very *very* hard to change a running system to handle these time zones. (Don't ask how I know it's hard!)

Comment: Thank you for such a good reply, but I still have no clue how to get the value of the <input "date"> so it can do the insert function automatically on onClick={this.add}..